# Jenkins. How I can create variabels common for multiple Jobs?

Tags: jenkins

Sorry for my English, I'm Russian
I have 2 Jenkins Jobs: Job1 and Job2. I need to have some variables, that Job1 and Job2 may read/write in Jenkins file. E.t.c common versions, build numbers.
Simplify, I need map(key, value) that any Job can write and read.
How I can do it in Jenkins?

I try use Build parameters, but Jenkins-file can't write in Parameter, but I need do that.

Answer (score 0):

Any variables you set while the job is running won't affect anything in a global scale. Therefore, you can't set the value of a global variable from a job and expect it to persist.

This means you will have to look at external ways to solve your problem. You could have it added as a value in a key-value store on some cloud provider, or have it added as a database entry in a local database. The easiest option is to have the data stored in a file that both jobs can access.

To make things easier, you can use the [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject-Plugin.html) plugin, which allows you to specify a properties file. The properties file can hold key value pairs and be injected into your job before it runs. You can also modify the properties file directly from the job.

Comment: If we store the data in a file where both jobs can access.. at some point of time,, There will be race condition right.. one of the job will fail unless these are sequential jobs instead of parallel jobs..

Comment: @hackwithharsha yes, that will happen. If we are simply talking about writing a single value to a file, then the operation would be fast enough that the chances of this happening are small. If we are talking about an operation that takes a while, then it's better to go for a key value store that will be accessible concurrently.